# Is it possible to create mobile app in streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, android-camera, session-state, streamlit

I am trying to create mobile app in streamlit but I have no idea how to do that could someone help me to create streamlit mobile app by giving example

In mobile app we should take pictures and crop the same.

Comment: I dont think you can, but you can still adapt your website so it can be used from a mobile phone

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So their is no way that I can use streamlit app from mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some external libraries or frameworks that provide the necessary functionality for capturing and cropping images.

One option is to use the Python Pillow library, which provides functions for reading and manipulating image files. You can use the Image.open() function to open an image file, and the Image.crop() function to crop the image. You can then use Streamlit's st.image() function to display the cropped image in your app.

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image

# Open an image file
image = Image.open("image.jpg")

# Crop the image
# The crop() function takes a tuple of (left, upper, right, lower) coordinates
# that define the bounding box for the cropped image.
cropped_image = image.crop((100, 100, 200, 200))

# Display the cropped image
st.image(cropped_image)
```